# How to implement a list of a specific concrete class from the abstract class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, arraylist, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have an abstract class "Actor" and it should generate a list (ArrayList, maybe the best option) of one of the concrete classes implemented, lets use "Actor1".
There are three or more concrete classes Actor1,2,3... that are made using the factory method and all of them must have the list of Actor1(s) created.

Any suggestion?

ok, I didn't expected such a fast response. Well, as I don't get it were to start with, some of the code is this, so far:

```
public abstract class Actor implements IActor { 
   protected Coordinates coordinates;
   protected List<Actor> actor1;
   public Actor(Coordinates coordinates) { 
      this.coordinates = coordinates;    
      //How to implemet the list? 
   } 

   public Coordinates getLocation() { 
      return coordinates; 
   }

   public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates) { 
      this.coordinates = coordinates; 
   }
```

Comment: it might help, if you explain what you want to achieve in the end - maybe your approach is not the best way of implementing it.

Comment: Yeah get coding..... Or explain a little bit more....

Comment: It's really not clear what your question is. How would you like us to help you?

Comment: You are missing a closing `}`

Answer (score 1):

I would make Actor a generic type bounded to itself, and then restrict it further in the concrete subclasses.

```
public abstract class Actor<A extends Actor<A>> {

    public List<A> getActors() { ...

}

public class Actor1 extends Actor<Actor1> { ...
```

That way, `getActors` from `Actor1` will return a `List<Actor1>`.